# Trouble with encoding passing a QString to sqlite3_open

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I'm trying to use the `sqlite3` library with Qt.

I have my database path stored in a `QString`. Since `sqlite3_open` wants a `const char*`, I tried doing the following:

```cpp
const QString qpath = whateverGivesIt();
const char* path = qpath.toUtf8().constData();
sqlite3_open(path, &connection);
```

With little success. If I use

```
qDebug() << qpath;
qDebug() << path;
```

Both of them give me the same (right) path. But SQLite3 seems not to be accepting it, since I see a new file being created: `hЮUUU`. Also, the database to which I'm connected is of obviously empty, as it seems that SQLite3 is connecting to a new file.

Any ideas? Please suggest (:

Answer (score 1):

Qt has its own implementation for sqlite which works in a stable way with QObjects check : http://katecpp.github.io/sqlite-with-qt/